# Authorization header not working in NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to send cid=@"value" as a authorization header with `NSMutableURLRequest`. But it throws an error. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"APIAccessKey"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cid=\"%@\"", @"hdemPsqxVSVSJCRSt8PHmUHUyUtXk="]    forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

But the API returning this error:

```
 <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fff0a41de80> { URL: http://url } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 31;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 26 May 2015 11:36:50 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    "App-Authenticate" = "Basic Scheme='API' location='https:url";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }
```

Comment: Would it work if you use '' instead of the one that you are using. 
NSString *authorizationHeaderValue = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"cid='%@'", authorizationToken]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]
                                autorelease];

[request setValue:VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:@"field to set"];
```

or to add a header:

```
[request addValue:VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:@"field to set"];
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work with NSMutableURLRequest, and it's discouraged by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableURLRequest/allHTTPHeaderFields), but I don't know why. Applies to `Authorization, Connection, Host, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authorization, WWW-Authenticate`. I don't know why it's discouraged, so if anyone knows speak up. :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no HTTP header called 'APIAccessKey'. So instead of writing

```
[request setValue:@"value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"APIAccessKey"];
```

you should use,

```
[request addValue:@"value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"APIAccessKey"];
```

Comment: What you suggest here will simply append "value" to the "APIAccessKey" header's existing value (if any). It won't "add" a new header.